# Why won't my object be removed from stage? AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

Hello there I am making a simple game using Flash AS2 and I don't know how you can remove an object from the stage.

I have a simple object called "Enemy" having the following code:

```
 onClipEvent(enterFrame) {  
             if (hitTest(_root.charBoy)) _root.life--;
             function remove()  { 
             this.removeMovieClip();    
             } 
  }
```

I then try to call the remove function when my "Bullet" object hits it like this:

```
if (hitTest(_root.Enemy))
    {
        _root[Enemy].remove();
        this.removeMovieClip();
    }
```

But the only thing that happens is that only the Bullet object gets removed and the Enemy AI stays on the stage.

I have also tried the following variations on declaring the function:

```
onClipEvent(load)
{
    function remove()
    {
        this.removeMovieClip();
    }
    remove();   
}
onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
    if (hitTest(_root.charBoy)) _root.life--;
}
```

and

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
    if (hitTest(_root.charBoy)) _root.life--;
    function remove()
    {
        this.removeMovieClip();
    }
    remove();
}
```

Which still does the same thing. I have also tried `stage.removeChild(this)` but it doesn't do anything.

Please tell me how I can solve this, I have set the enemies on the stage and have simple AI movements and not programmatically duplicating them.

How can I remove them from stage when my `Bullet` hits the certain object.

My `Bullet` object can already track them and `hits` them so the `Bullet` itself is removed form the stage yet the enemy object stays.

Comment: This looks like AS2, not AS3.

Comment: `if (hitTest(_root.Enemy))
    {
        _root.Enemy.remove();
        this.removeMovieClip();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with quotes around 'Enemy'

```
_root["Enemy"].remove();
```

or as suggested above

```
_root.Enemy.remove();
```